# Only one Modal Pops Up - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having a problem with bootstrap - Only one of the modals is popping up! I've reviewed the code and couldn't find what the problem is. The first modal is exactly coded like the others, so I don't know what's going wrong. Here's a CodePen (like a jsFiddle): [CodePen](http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/tcypf)

And here is the code:
References

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Thumbnail Gallery

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#somo" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#groth" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#gibson" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#baskin" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#obrien" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#coh" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#chada" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="span3"><a href="#panikkar" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-polaroid" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Modals

```
<div id="somo" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
<h3>Meagan Somo</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div id="groth" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Desi Groth</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="gibson" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Jessie Gibson</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="baskin" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Connor Baskin</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="obrien" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Nik O'Brien</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="coh" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Elizabeth Coh</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="chada" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Rachel Chada</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div><div id="panikkar" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h3>Manoj Panikkar</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
```

For the full code, check out the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/tcypf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `</div>` at the end of your first `<div class="modal-footer">`

Comment: Of course I am. Even after spending an hour reviewing the code, I couldn't catch that. Maybe it's time to get off the computer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a close `</div>` tag to your modal-footer in all of them.  Should be:

```
<div id="somo" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Meagan Somo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/230x270" alt="" class="pull-left">Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Properly indent your code, it'll save you tons of time in the long run.

Comment: My code is indented on Notepad++, but for some reason the indents get all weird when I paste in in here. Thank you btw.